# ant zip; exclude all sub-directories and files

Tags: ant, zip

When creating a zip from ant, how can I exclude all sub directories and files from a given directory?

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to prevent them from being included in the zip

```
<target name="zip">
    <zip destfile="C:\Projects\example\builds\.zip"
            excludes="C:\Projects\example\logs\**\*.*">
    ...

    ...
    </zip>
</target>
```

From reading the documentation, and from reading the [ant definitive guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001841) I would assume that `**\` should exclude any directory, and `*.*` would exclude any file of any extension

I want to include the `logs` directory, but nothing inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

1. Change the name of your `destfile` to `"C:\Projects\example\builds\logs.zip"`
2. Set your `basedir` to `"C:\Projects\example\"`
3. Change your `excludes` value to `"C:\Projects\example\logs\**\*"` (that means any file)

Another option might be to use the `project`-defined `basedir`, and change all your paths to relative UNIX-like values.